# android AlarmManager with AIR native extension not work

Tags: android, air, alarmmanager, flex-mobile, air-native-extension

I'm trying to create an AIR native extension for sending scheduled notifications, I have the following code:

```
package com.ane.notification.functions;

public class ScheduledNotificationFunction implements FREFunction {

  Context androidActivity;
  Context androidContext;

  @Override
  public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
      androidActivity = context.getActivity();
      androidContext = androidActivity.getApplicationContext();
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) androidContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
      Intent intent = new Intent(androidContext, SendNotification.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(androidContext, id, intent, 0);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis()+30000), pendingIntent);
      return null;
    }
}
```

Class SendNotification

```
package com.ane.notification.functions;

public class SendNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // Send Notification Code
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.ane.notification"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
   <application android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <receiver android:name=".functions.SendNotification"/>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

The problem is that not called SendNotification once marks the definite time to send the notification. I think the ScheduledNotificationFunction code is fine, since I have put in a try / catch and does not generate exceptions, so I assume the alert is register in the system.

I'm not very familiar with programming in android, so anything missing on this wrong or let me know, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use actions to filter these sort of requests so you should have something that looks more like this:

```
long fireTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000;

Intent intent = new Intent( "com.ane.notification.functions.SOME_ACTION" );
PendingIntent delayPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, fireTime, delayPendingIntent);
```

Then you need to add that manifest addition to your AIR application descriptor not the Android Manifest. Also you need to use the full class package in the manifest:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto" >
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <application> 
                <receiver android:name="com.ane.notification.functions.SendNotification">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.ane.notification.functions.SOME_ACTION"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
            </application>
        </manifest>

    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

You must register the receiver in the manifest for the system to call it when the application isn't running. You can do it in code if you just want a receiver while your application is running and not deal with the manifest additions then.

Note: If your application has been stopped before the alarm fires your FREContext won't be initialised even though you'll be able to run code in your SendNotification receiver.